# Ruby file copy produces different file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, rest, temporary-files

I'm not very familiar with file handling in ruby.  A problem I've come accross is that reading and writing a binary file doesn't produce exactly the same file.

`clone = Tempfile.new(tempfile.original_filename)`
`FileUtils.copy_stream(tempfile, clone)`
`clone.flush`

From the image below it is clear that it is not an exact file copy, when I try to open the newly created file in an image viewer it reports that the file is corrupt.  I have tried copying the file in different ways such as `clone.write(tempfile.read)`, etc. without success.

[image: File compare]
**The file viewer also indicates the original is ANSI Dos/Windows and the clone is ANSI Macintosh.  The file size also differs by about 200 bytes.*

What I'm trying to accomplish is actually simply using a Tempfile twice.  A file is uploaded via rails and given to me as a Tempfile.  I want to submit it to two different restful services and `RestClient.post` closes the file automatically.  Another option would be to submit some sort of in memory stream clone to RestClient so that it can not close my file.  If I submit `File.open(tempfile.path)` to RestClient it produces the same broken file, this indicates that the reading is the problem and not the writing.  If I submit the original Tempfile object to RestClient it works perfectly but then it is closed and deleted and I cannot send it again.

Please help!

Regards,
Pierre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be much more helpful to see a hex view of these files instead of a text editor's intepretation. My guess is that at least one of the files is not opened in binary mode. In Ruby 1.9, try

```
open(filename, 'rb')
open(filename, 'wb')
Tempfile.new(filename, :binmode => true)
```

for opening a file for reading / writing and to create a binary temporary file, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, my final solution is that I don't create another tempfile, I simply pass a file.open in binmode.